# How to I change these numbers into a score out of 100

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms

I have the following numbers in an excel file and I am trying to work out how to transform these into a score from 1 to 100. The bottom number (0.1) should be a 1 and the top number (61.2) should be 100. Here are the numbers.

0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.9, 2.5, 7.5, 11.0, 13.6, 15.5, 16.1, 21.7, 22.1, 27.8, 28.0, 36.0, 44.4, 47.3, 47.4, 52.3, 61.2.

It is not clear as to what is the best function to use in excel to generate the algorithm. Any help here is most appreciated.

Comment: Transform in what sense? One way would be to just multiply them all by the constant $100/61.2$, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe "scale" is the best term to use?

Answer (score 1):

Use a linear transformation.  Take $1 = m*0.1 + b$ and $100 = m*61.2 + b$.  Solve for $m$ and $b$.  Plug the elements of the list into $x$ in $y = mx + b$.

And don't use Excel for real analysis.

Comment: I agree. However, I know there are many non-tech savy professors that believe Excel is 'good' for Real Analysis. Sadly, I know a few such professors.